# React-Hooks: State's Peculiar Behavior when working with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

**I am getting different results in react-native (Probably will be similar in reactjs) when using different techniques to setState to an array.
The code is actually longer but here's the summarized version.**

> **CODE i.e NOT WORKING**

```
const [a,seta] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    callfun();
})
function callfun(){
       var newArray = [];
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
           newArray.push(<Text>{i}</Text>)
      }
      seta(newArray);            //LINE 10
}
return(
<View>{a}</View>         // LINE 13
);
```

> The code above only display the first element of the array when rendering.

---

Replacing Line 10 by

```
seta(newArray);
```

Replacing Line 13 by

```
<View>{[...newArray]}</View>
```

> This code above only renders the first elements in the array.

> **WORKING CODE**

Replacing Line 10 by

```
seta([newArray]);
```

Replacing Line 13 by

```
<View>{i[0]}</View>
```

> This code above gives the correct result and renders all the elements in the state array.

---

Replacing Line 10 by

```
seta([...newArray]);
```

Replacing Line 13 by

```
<View>{i}</View>
```

> This code above gives the correct result and renders all the elements in the state array.

**MY GUESS**

There is some problem with seta(arrayValue). I was not able to find any reason why this is not working.

Comment: What do you want to do, exactly? I don't see any specific question.

Comment: I would like to know the reason  behind this peculiar behavior of react.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `map` function to show all element

```
const [a,seta] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    callfun();
})
function callfun(){
       var newArray = [];
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
           newArray.push(<Text key={i} >{i}</Text>)
      }
      seta(newArray);            //LINE 10
}
return(
<View>{a.map(el => el)}</View>         // LINE 13
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. `a.map(el => el)` will return the array similar to `a` itself. How does that make any difference? Besides, arrays can be rendered by passing the variable in curly brackets like in the question: `{ a }`.

Comment: You are right ,I didn't pay attention to that. have you tried `<Text key={i} >{i}</Text>`

Comment: Yeah but the question is why  it is producing those results. I was able to do it.